# Laravel Error 503 Service Unavailable Service

Tags: php, laravel, server, cpanel

Error 503 Service Unavailable
Service Unavailable

Guru Meditation:
XID: 5312211

Varnish cache server

I working on cpanel and subdomain but i got this error from laravel project. do you can help me to solve this?
I using cpanel and laravel 5.5

Comment: if your project is hosted at WHM, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62829559/7955629

Answer (score 55):

Looks like you ran the artisan down command, but not the up command.
Just run:

```
php artisan up
```

and than you will get:

> "Application is now live."

Comment: For the curious, the `php artisan down` command writes a file to `storage/framework/down`, the presence of which signals the condition in question. Conversely, `php artisan up` deletes the aforementioned file.

Comment: Worked! I LOVE YOU, no really..

Answer (score 13):

if have tried `php artisan up` command and your site still not up and gives 503 then ,

> delete **down** file inside /storage/framework/

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem in Cpanel what i have did to fix this.

I just have fixed PHP version to the latest
then I goes to "Shell option in panel" and entered this command and my app is live now.   `php artisan up`

Answer (score 3):

The cause of the error likely stems from Apache and PHP-FPM becoming overloaded with requests. PHP-FPM, and occasionally Apache, will need adjustments to their limitations to get around this.

To start, we recommend attempting to adjust the PHP-FPM pool limits from within the WHM "MultiPHP Manager."

To do so globally (for all domains):

```
[1] Access WHM >> MultiPHP Manager
[2] Select "System PHP-FPM Configuration"
[3] Adjust the "Max Children" and "Max Requests" fields. We recommend incrementing in values of 5 to 10 to ensure that PHP-FPM does not get overloaded.
[4] Save your configuration settings
```

[image: global]

To perform these changes by domain (for particular domain):

```
[1] Access WHM >> MultiPHP Manager
[2] Scroll down and locate a domain that experiences the problem.
[3] Select "Edit PHP-FPM" for the domain in question.
[4] Adjust the "Max Children" and "Max Requests" fields.
[5] Save your configuration settings
```

[image: domain]

Answer (score 3):

If you have run `php artisan down` previously then you may face this issue.
You have to make this up using `php artisan up` command

**Why this happened?** as I did the same mistake `php artisan down` and then run

```
 php artisan serve
```

and CLI was showing me

```
<http://127.0.0.1:8000>
[Thu Dec 31 00:25:23 2020] PHP 7.4.3 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
```

application started but it was showing **503 service Unavailable** then `run php artisan up` and  application started.

run this command to make this workable

`php artisan up`

Comment: I accidentally ran `artisan down` instead of `composer down`. This solution helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you get "Laravel Error 503 Service Unavailable Service" but there is no info in log file, check filesystem status. You may have filled up disk space. Check what's filling it:

```
cd / && sudo du -h --max-depth=1 -x
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Laravel 10

My php version is 8.2xx

Open public directory

Edit .htaccess

and add this line

"<"IfModule mime_module">"

AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php82 .php .php8 .phtml

"</"IfModule">"

delete qoutes from text

Save and refresh, It works.

Answer (score -3):

If you have tried the

```
 php artisan up
```

And you are still getting the 503 error

**You should try disabling OPcache.**

To disable OPcache on cPanel, you can follow these steps:

1. Log in to your cPanel account.
2. Navigate to the "Software" section and click on "Select PHP Version"
   or "MultiPHP Manager" (the exact wording may vary depending on your
   cPanel version).
3. In the PHP version selector, choose the PHP version for which you
   want to disable OPcache. If you have multiple PHP versions
   installed, make sure to select the one your website is using.
4. Click on the "Options" tab or a similar option that allows you to
   customize PHP options.
5. Look for the "opcache" or "OPcache" option in the list of available
   extensions or modules.
6. Uncheck or disable the "opcache" or "OPcache" option.
7. Save the changes or click on "Apply" to apply the updated PHP
   configuration.
8. Verify that OPcache is disabled by accessing your website and
   checking if the changes take effect.

**Note:** The steps may vary slightly depending on the cPanel version and theme you are using. If you're unsure or don't have access to disable OPcache from cPanel, you may need to contact your hosting provider for assistance.

Comment: out of curiosity, was this written by an AI such as chatgpt?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).  If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34573659)

Answer (score -11):

503 Service Unavailable
The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state