# I got the 503 error on import an excel file on cpanel laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, maatwebsite-excel

```
    <?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\ExcelValidation;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\HasReferencesToOtherSheets;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCalculatedFormulas;

class Validation implements ToCollection, WithCalculatedFormulas, HasReferencesToOtherSheets
{
    private $upload_id = '';

    /**
     * Validation constructor.
     *
     * @param $id
     */
    public function  __construct($id)
    {
        $this->upload_id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @param Collection $rows
     */
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        ini_set("max_execution_time", "-1");
        ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");
        set_time_limit(0);

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            if (!empty($row[6]) && !empty($row[3]) && (strtolower($row[6]) == 'accurate' ||  strtolower($row[6]) == 'error')) {
                $obj = new ExcelValidation();
                $obj->status = strtolower($row[6]);
                $obj->user_id =  loginId();
                $obj->excel_upload_id =  $this->upload_id;
                $obj->day_id =  (int)date('w');
                $obj->week =  (int)date('W');
                $obj->month_id =  (int)date('m');
                $obj->year =  (int)date('Y');
                $obj->source = $row[3];
                $obj->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> This is my code.
> Every thing is working fine on my local machine but when try to import file on the live server it gives 503 error.
> Its been 3 days i am working for its solution but all in vain. I have updated the execution_time to 1600 and post_max_size to 1024mbs and everything to maximum but did'nt work.
> Here is the error.
> ***Service Unavailable
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
> Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.***
> Please help me if anyone has know the solution. Thanks

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514228/laravel-error-503-service-unavailable-service. this may help

Comment: I had already done this but did not work

Comment: I had run these commands in the routes
Route::get('clear-all', function () {
    Artisan::call('config:cache');
    Artisan::call('config:clear');
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    Artisan::call('route:clear');
    Artisan::call('optimize:clear');
    Artisan::call('up');
    dd('done');
});

Comment: What else did you try to resolve the problem? Does your server's error log contain any details?

Comment: No there is no error in server log.
Its in my code because the file is too large so that i have to chunk the file data and its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of **WithChunkReading** resole my problem.
The problem is that i have excel file that have refernce with other excel files in the same file and when its calculating the formula it takes too much time of reading data. So i used "withChunkReading" in my import its works fine.
Here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\ExcelValidation;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\HasReferencesToOtherSheets;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCalculatedFormulas;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;

class Validation implements ToCollection, WithCalculatedFormulas, HasReferencesToOtherSheets, **WithChunkReading**
{
    private $upload_id = '';

    /**
     * Validation constructor.
     *
     * @param $id
     */
    public function  __construct($id)
    {
        $this->upload_id = $id;
    }
    
    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 1000;
    }

    /**
     * @param Collection $rows
     */
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {

        $arr = [];
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            if (!empty($row[6]) && !empty($row[3]) && (strtolower($row[6]) == 'accurate' ||  strtolower($row[6]) == 'error')) {
                $arr[$count]['status'] = strtolower($row[6]);
                $arr[$count]['user_id'] = loginId();
                $arr[$count]['excel_upload_id'] = $this->upload_id;
                $arr[$count]['day_id'] = (int)date('w');
                $arr[$count]['week'] = (int)date('W');
                $arr[$count]['month_id'] = (int)date('m');
                $arr[$count]['year'] = (int)date('Y');
                $arr[$count]['source'] = $row[3];
                $count++;
            }
        }
        ExcelValidation::insert($arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Also, if that linked question resolved your problem, please mark your question as a duplicate of that other question instead of copying their answer

Comment: I had added explanation on the top please have a look. Thanks